# asp.net web api - action filter - cannot access posted json object from request object

Tags: asp.net-web-api

In asp.net web api we could use an action filter [ValidateModel] for logging purposes:
it would be useful to log the json string from the request for the action method parameter (say a car object) in case there is a binding error due to sending a string when a decimal is expected.
in those cases car object is null.

Issue - cannot access posted json object from request object

```
//var car = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

or

```
//var car2 = actionContext.ControllerContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

How could I get the json string for the Car parameter in the Action Filter attribute ValidateModel?
say for method:

```
//[ValidateModel]
  //public HttpResponseMessage Post_Car(Car car) {
//}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, you want to log requests in case there is a binding error. A binding error is somewhat exception so that you may handle exceptions of your controller or actions. To do this, you need to use`ExceptionFilterAttribute` . The example below :

```
public class ExceptionHandlingAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        string content = actionExecutedContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        ///LOGGING ACTIONS

        base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think binding errors can be caught as exceptions.             I wanted to be able to log action method's parameters in a generic way for tracing purposes that is from an action filter before it hits the action method, problem is I cannot access the content from there, thanks